# $ct' = γ(ct − βx)$

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

[image]

I was reading a paper on S.R. saw this eq: $ct' = \gamma(ct − \beta x)$.
However I am confused by the Minkowski's diagram:
We know $\tan \theta = \frac{x}{ct}= \beta$. 
However, wouldn't it also mean $\tan \theta = \frac{ct}{x}= \beta$? (when using the theta closer to the $x$ axis)
If that happens, wouldn't $ct=\beta x$ regardless of $t'$?
Sorry if what I'm saying don't make sense, because I'm really very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which event in space-time is described by the coordinates $ct$ and $x$. In first case the event is located on the $c\tilde t$ axis ins second case on the $\tilde x$ axis.

While a pair of coordinates on the $c\tilde t$ axis has a physical interpretation as the coordinates of an observer which is comoving with the "tilded" reference frame, which is a pair of coordinates which is natural to consider, a pair of coordinates on the $\tilde x$ axis has no such natural interpretation, it would be an event which is at equal time $\tilde t$ as the origin - why would you want so consider such an event?

Comment: *an event which is comoving*. Events don't move. Events are
*points of spacetime*.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\tan \theta = x/ct$ is the equation of the $\tilde{t}$ axis. The equation  $\tan \theta = ct/x$ is the equation of the $\tilde{x}$ axis. If you require both equations to be true at the same time, then the only solution is $(t,x)=(0,0)$, which is the intersection of the two axes.